# WGET how to exclude "domain.com/?p=" pages

Tags: wget

When using WGET -m to archive a website, what is the command to exclude all pages with the address /?p=  after the domain ?

example.. exclude these pages...

```
www.domain.com/?p=1
www.domain.com/?p=2
www.domain.com/?p=3
```

I know there's the -X option to exclude a list of folders but these are not really folders. Also there's the reject -R option but this only applies to file name suffixes which this is also not. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest trying [`--reject-regex urlregex`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options.html) option

> Specify a regular expression to(...)reject the complete URL.

Comment: That's worked thanks. However I've realised I need to use two expressions. Can this be done with reject-rejex ?   e.g.   ignore   /?p=   and    /?b=     (WGET version is 1.19)

Comment: @Matt this can be done with single expression, use `[pb]` which will be understood as `p` or `b`